# How to prove that the following simplification rule is satisfiability-equivalent?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, computational-complexity, boolean-algebra, satisfiability

Denote $F\overset{\text{SAT}}{\equiv}G$ if $F \in SAT {\iff} G \in SAT$.

A transformation of formulas $S(·)$ is called satisfiability-equivalent if $\forall{F}\space F\overset{\text{SAT}}{\equiv}S(F)$.

How to prove that the following simplification rule is satisfiability-equivalent and
show how to re-construct a satisfying assignment for the original formula $F$ from a satisfying assignment for
the simplified formula:
**Blocked clause removal (the rule removes a blocked clause from $F$).**

N.B.- *Blocked clause:* A literal $\ell$ in a clause $C$ blocks it if  $\forall{D}\in F (\bar\ell \in D 
\implies |C \cap \overline{D}| \geq 2)$, that is, if
$\bar\ell\in D$, then $C$ and $D$ must also have at least one other pair of contrary literals.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?
Generally, for this kind of problem I would start by working through some examples and try to see what happens there.

Comment: @GraffL Actually I have no clue to start, give me little bit details how to start.

Comment: As I said: I would start by working through some examples. This will a) ensure that you understand the problem statement including all the relevant definitions and b) should give you some ideas of how to start with the proof. If you get stuck then (or already by working through the example), this should at least make at clear to you where exactly you are currently stuck. Then, you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: Once you are ready to start the proof itself: You have to show two implications. One is trivial (why?), one requires some work. For the latter: As the task already suggests: Try to construct a satisfying assignment for the original formula from one for the simplified formula. Consider, in particular, the special (blocking) literal $\ell$

Answer (score 3):

Since OP said, they don't know how to start, I will try to provide an outline for a possible proof:

### What do we have to prove?

The stated claim is that deleting a blocked clause from a SAT-formula does not change its satisfiability.
So, let $F$ be some SAT-formula with a blocked clause $C$ (blocked by a literal $\ell \in C$) and let $G$ be the SAT-formula obtained from $F$ by deleting $C$. We then have to show that $F$ has a satisfying assignment if and only if $G$ has a satisfying assignment. Thus, we have to show two implications:

1. $F$ satisfiable $\implies G$ satisfiable
2. $G$ satisfiable $\implies F$ satisfiable

### The trivial direction (1.)

Since deleting a clause only makes it easier to satisfy a SAT-formula, the first implication is trivial. To double check whether this is really clear: How can you get a satisfying assignment of $G$ from one of $F$?

### The interesting directions (2.)

Here, we can assume that we have some satisfying assignment $\beta$ for $G$. If this assignment also satisfies $F$, we are done. So, it suffices to consider the case where the assignment $\beta$ does not satisfy $F$.

As $F$ and $G$ only differ in the clause $C$, this must mean that $\beta$ does not satisfy this clause $C$ (i.e. sets *all* literals in $C$ to False). Our goal, therefore, must be to somehow change $\beta$ such that it also satisfies $C$ while still satisfying all other clauses.

Now, how can we make sure that $C$ is satisfied? We have to set one of the literals in $C$ to True. But there is only one literal we know to be in $C$: The literal $\ell$! So, let's try setting this literal to True (while keeping all other assignments as in $\beta$:

This certainly satisfies $C$. And what about the other clauses? To check that those are still satisfied, take any such clause $D \neq C$ and consider the following three cases:

1. $D$ contains neither $\ell$ nor $\bar \ell$
2. $D$ contains $\ell$
3. $D$ contains $\bar\ell$

We have to show that $D$ is satisfied by the new assignment in all three cases. Case 1 and 2 are easy (why?), in case 3 we should probably use the definition of a blocked clause (since we haven't used it yet) together with our assumption that $C$ wasn't satisfied by the original assignment $\beta$.