# Application of blocked clauses

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, satisfiability

I read from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4848606/how-to-prove-that-the-following-simplification-rule-is-satisfiability-equivalent), I have not understood $G$ satisfiable $\implies F$ satisfiable section. In this section case3 is $D$ contains $\bar\ell$.

And author said in the last line "blocked clause (since we haven't used it yet) together with our assumption that $C$ wasn't satisfied by the original assignment $\beta$".

My question is how to use blocked clause definition  here? How definition and  "$C$ wasn't satisfied by the original assignment $\beta$" use together?

I mean  accurately why everything is OK in "case 3" ,yes, using the definition, but please explain how?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Where are you stuck? It is really difficult to answer this question without a bit more context

Comment: @GraffL I use that question context means (blocked clause definition etc) which may be sufficient, I understand everything, but this last not able to digest.

Comment: @GraffL my understanding is that D contains l', and l in C, so C and D have contrary pair, at least one. So we remove the clause C, by using blocked clause definition. Then F is reduced to G. Am I correct?Please tell.

Comment: Your statements are correct statements, but I am not really sure what their significance is? If they are supposed to be a proof of case 3, then no, this is not a proof.
What you have to prove is why the constructed assignment satisfies $F$ (or, more specifically, clause $D$)

Comment: @GraffL I mean accurately why everything is OK in "case 3" ,yes, using the definition, but please explain how? You just explain, just elaborate little bit by which everybody can understand. That's it. Not the proof. It's the main point of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will start from the basic definition and we will use a simple example to support the argument.

*Definition*: a clause $C$ is *blocked by* a literal $l \in C$ in a CNF formula $F$ if all binary resolvents of $C$ upon $l$ with clauses from $F \setminus \{ C \}$ are tautologies.

*Example*: the clause $C = ¬P \lor Q$ is *blocked* by literal $¬P$ in $F = \{ P \lor ¬Q, ¬Q \lor R \}$ because the only resolvent of $C$ upon $¬P$ is the tautology $Q \lor ¬Q$, obtained by resolving with clause $D = P \lor ¬Q$.

The argument assumes that we have some satisfying assignment $\beta$ for $G = F \setminus \{ C \}$ that does not satisfy $F$ and we want to define a new assignment $\beta'$ that will do.

But $F$ and $G$ only differ in the clause $C$, and thus $β$ does not satisfy $C$, i.e. $\beta(C)= \bot$.

The way to satisfy $C$ is to set one of the literals in $C$ to $\top$, but we know only one literal of $C$: the literal $l$ [$\lnot P$ in our example]. So, we try with
$\beta'(l)= \top$ (while keeping all other assignments as in $\beta$) that implies $\beta'(C)=\top$, and we have to check how all other clauses of $F$ are satisfied by $\beta'$.

Then three cases: case 1) neither $l$ nor $\overline l$ are in $D$; it is not affected by the new value for $l$. 2) $l \in D$, an thus $\beta'(l)= \top$ implies $\beta' (D)= \top$.

And now case 3): $\overline l \in D$. But we have that $C$ was blocked by $l$ if $F$ and this means that *all binary resolvents of $C$ upon $l$ with clauses from $F \setminus \{ C \}$ are tautologies*: thus, the resolvent of $C$ and $D$ must be a tautology, i.e. there must be a literal $k \in D$ such that $\overline k \in C$ [see example above, where $C = \lnot P \lor Q$ and $D = P \lor \lnot Q$].

But we have assumed that for the original assigment $\beta$: $\beta (C)= \bot$ that means that **every** literal in $C$ must be falsified by $\beta$ and thus also $\beta(\overline k)=\bot$, i.e. $\beta (k)=\top$.

Thus, we have $k \in D$ and $\beta' (k)= \beta(k)= \top$ tha means that $\beta'(D)= \top$.